# How to use port 80 in a boost::asio server?

Tags: c++, http, boost, port, boost-asio

I'm using the [boost::asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) library.

I've been trying to run my server on port 80, but can't get it to do so. Below is the culpable line in my code, with outcomes in the comments:

```
// This runs fine, and the webpage is visible on localhost:8000
tcp::acceptor a(*io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 8000));

// This throws an error (at this line)
tcp::acceptor a(*io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 80));

// This runs fine, but the webpage is NOT visible on localhost or localhost:80
tcp::acceptor a(*io_service, tcp::endpoint());
```

I've noticed that endpoint only accepts four-digit port numbers. Could this have something to do with it?

**How can I see my page running on port 80? Thanks!**

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: Ports below 1024 are reserved for system use, and you have to have elevated privileges to open those ports.

Comment: @sgarza62: That is a unix-derivative, so yes, you can only bind to ports below 1024 as `root`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure how it works on Windows, but on Unix, including Linux, ports below 1024 can only be bound by privileged processes. Try running it as `root`. Of course you should give up the permissions (using `setuid` system call) after opening the port.